# TableMappings With TableName Instead of TableN

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am not sure this is possible, but I just cant figured it out. 
I have a SP in my DB as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMyValue]
AS
  SELECT Code, TypeDesc FROM IDType
  SELECT Code, Race FROM Race
  SELECT Code, Nation FROM Nationality
  SELECT Code, [Language name] AS 'Language' FROM Languages 
  SELECT Code, Occupation FROM Occupation
  SELECT Code, Country FROM Country
GO
```

What I am trying to do is map the table with the table name from DB [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.TableMappings.Add("IDType", "NRICType")
da.TableMappings.Add("Race", "Race")
da.TableMappings.Add("Nationality", "Nationality")
da.TableMappings.Add("Languages", "Languages")
da.TableMappings.Add("Occupation", "Occupation")
da.TableMappings.Add("Country", "Country")

da.Fill(ds)
```

instead of using TableN like this:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "NRICType")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Race")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Nationality")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table3", "Languages")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table4", "Occupation")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table5", "Country")

da.Fill(ds)
```

Anyway, it doesn't seem working as when I try to access the value in the later part with `Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("NRICType")`. The `ds.Tables("NRICType")` appears to be `NULL`. Everything work fine when I map it with TableN.

But the problem might happen in future is, what if the sequence of `SELECT STATEMENT` in SP changed? The mapping will definitely mess up. Code in C# would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chinz,

Here is a Hack that will give you what you are looking for...

In your Stored procedure add one additional field (TableName) to your selects

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMyValue]
AS
  SELECT 'IDType' TableName, Code, TypeDesc FROM IDType
  SELECT  'Race' TableName, Code, Race FROM Race
  SELECT  'Nationality' TableName, Code, Nation FROM Nationality
  SELECT  'Languages' TableName, Code, [Language name] AS 'Language' FROM Languages 
  SELECT  'Occupation' TableName, Code, Occupation FROM Occupation
  SELECT  'Country' TableName, Code, Country FROM Country
GO
```

Now in your c# code after the da.Fill(ds)

```
da.Fill(ds);
   for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
   {
       if (i == 0)
           da.TableMappings.Add("table", GetTableName(i, ds));
       else
           da.TableMappings.Add("table" + i.ToString(), GetTableName(i, ds));

   }
```

GetTableName is a method to grab the first field from the DataTable

```
static string GetTableName(int tableIndex, DataSet ds)
{
    if (ds.Tables[tableIndex].Rows.Count > 0)
        return ds.Tables[tableIndex].Rows[0]["TableName"].ToString();
    // If there aren't any rows I don't know the Table name and return table[index] as the name
    return "table" + tableIndex.ToString();
}
```

Another way to do this is to make you first selection in the Stored Procedure the order and name of the Tables. Then in your c# code after the the da.Fill(ds) you can read the rows out of ds.tables[0] and use that for your table mappings.

I hope this helps.

If you don't want to deal with additional unwanted columns in your results, then consider the following

Your Stored Procedure will have an additional select which will be the first select and define the order of the tables being returned.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMyValue]
AS
    SELECT  'IDType' TableName, 1 as SortOrder
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Race' TableName , 2 as SortOrder
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Nationality' TableName , 3 as SortOrder
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Languages' TableName  ,4 as SortOrder
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Occupation' TableName , 5 as SortOrder
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Country' TableName, 6 as SortOrder
    ORDER BY SortOrder

    SELECT   Code, TypeDesc FROM IDType
    SELECT   Code, Race FROM Race
    SELECT   Code, Nation FROM Nationality
    SELECT   Code, [Language name] AS 'Language' FROM Languages 
    SELECT   Code, Occupation FROM Occupation
    SELECT   Code, Country FROM Country
GO
```

and in the c# code after the da.Fill(ds) do this

```
//string[] listOfTableNames;
listOfTableNames = GetTableNames(ds);
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
{
   da.TableMappings.Add("table" + i.ToString(), listOfTableNames[i]);
}
```

and GetTableNames Method is defined as

```
static string[] GetTableNames( DataSet ds)
{
    List<string> tablenames = new List<string>();

    // The first Table contains the TABLE NAMES
    tablenames.Add("TableNames"); 

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        foreach( DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            tablenames.Add(row["TableName"].ToString());
        }

    return tablenames.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: ,thanks. but with this, i will have whole brunch of duplicate value on TableName to be selected out. Not bad alternative through, would use this as last resourse. +1.

Comment: @chinz, I updated my answer to reflect your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation in MSDN thats the way it is supposed to be used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810286.aspx

If the Stored procedure is setup in that order, that order must be maintained in the future.

If you want to make this Dynimac you could verify the table schema and try to identify if you are looking at the correct table, but this will add a big cost in performance.

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "NRICType")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Race")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Nationality")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table3", "Languages")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table4", "Occupation")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table5", "Country")

da.Fill(ds)
```

Your second example is the correct use for this feature.

Comment: thanks. I went through the same article before. anyhow, it was 12years ago, I doubt if its still applies nowadays.